# Find accessibility element containing URL in Chrome

Tags: c, macos, accessibility

I am creating an application which uses MacOS accessibility API to retrieve browser URL.

My question is how can i know where is the URL stored. It seems it is different for every browser.

I have tried to use Accessibility Inspector but I dont see the name of the attribute

Thanks in advance and regards

Answer (score 0):

Chrome appears to support AppleScript, so the easiest way to do this is probably just to do something like:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    get the URL of the active tab of the front window
end tell
```

This is probably more stable than using the Accessibility API for this, as the layout of Chrome's browser windows may change, but the public scripting API probably shouldn't.

Comment: I know AppleScript but I want to use Accessibility